# Nested threadpool with different worker count

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I've started learning Python and came across a scenario where I have to implement two separate queues:

- I have N processes and two operations, O1 and O2.
- I want to run O1 with 4 workers.
- And O2 with 1 worker

My current code:

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

PROCESS_NUM = 4

o1_exe = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
o2_exe = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
    
def O1(x: int):
    print(f'O1: {x} started')
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f'O1: {x} complete')
    
def O2(x: int):
    print(f'O2: {x} started')
    time.sleep(2)
    print(f'O2: {x} complete')
    
def process(x: int):
    O1(x)
    o2_exe.submit(O2, x)

for i in range(0, PROCESS_NUM):
    o1_exe.submit(process, i)
```

I get the following Output:

```
O1: 0 started
O1: 0 complete
O1: 1 started
O1: 1 complete
O1: 2 started
O1: 2 complete
O1: 3 started
O1: 3 complete
```

The issue with my code is that O2 isn’t running at all.

Is there any other way to make this work or some solution with different approach?

I’m currently using Python 3.9.7

Comment: Why would it run considering you only submit `O1`, which doesn't call `O2` at all? Did you mean to submit `process` in the last line?

Comment: With that fix it works fine for me.

Comment: It's the same output for me [sshot](https://ibb.co/xJTfB1j)